# Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

I keep getting a Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, when it comes to the second &&

```
if Double(dependents.text!) ?? 1 >= 1 && Double(dependents.text!) ?? 1 <= 10 && Double(textField.text!)! >= 0.00  && Double(textField.text!)! <= 165.00 && marriageStatus.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
              fedTax.text = String(0.00)
          }
```

That is my code, the bold "&&" is where I get the error. 
If someone can help me, that would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you are force unwrapping `dependents.text!`- Check you have connected `dependents` outlet from storyboard. Otherwise, you could also safely unwrap it with

```
guard let dependentText = dependents.text! else {return}
```